# New Lines not being displayed in html <p> tag

Tags: html, sql-server, newline

Okay so basically my webpage retrieves a string from an SQL server and displays it inside `<p>` tag

retrieving the strings :

```
 requestedID=1;
var GetIns = "SELECT * FROM Inscriptions WHERE RecordID= '" + requestedID+ "'";
        var ins = db.Query(GetIns).ElementAt(0);
```

Displaying it :

```
<p> @ins.Text </p>
```

in SQL server the newlines are saved as char(10), i tried to replace them with char(10)+char(13) and even with a "`<br />`"

it displayed it as

```
line1 <br /> line2 <br /> line 3<br />
```

how to get it to read the break lines ?

Comment: This is likely a asp,net MVC issue, and you properly just need to use @Html.Raw once you've changed your linebreaks to <br>

Comment: it worked with @html.row thanks alot.